# Why can't i initialize opencv Mat in class

Tags: c++, class, opencv, pointers, mat

I tried to initialize constructor of Mat that is in class Source_Buffer but i gave me an error "A buffer overrun has occurred in ConsoleApplication4.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state. Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate the program."

```
# include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


class Source_Buffer {

public:
    Source_Buffer();
    int run();
private:
    const char* sffiename;
    Mat sfsrc; // this causes error
    Rect sfregion_of_interest;



};
Source_Buffer::Source_Buffer() :
sffiename("C:/ccc.jpg")
, sfsrc(imread(sffiename,0)) // and this
, sfregion_of_interest()
{

}

int Source_Buffer::run(){
    cout << "test" << endl;
    //Mat sfsrc = imread(sffiename, 0);
    sfregion_of_interest = Rect(90, 75, 250, 250);
    sfsrc = sfsrc(sfregion_of_interest);
(...)
return 0;
}
```

it works just fine after i extracted 'Mat sfsrc' and 'sffiename("C:/ccc.jpg")' on constructor from the class and put those into main function.
like `Mat sfsrc = imread(sffiename, 0);`

then i wanted to see if it work by just putting Mat sfsrc; to class as class member variable and not calling constructor for that
which is like

```
class Source_Buffer {

public:
    Source_Buffer();
    int run();
private:
    const char* sffiename;

    Rect sfregion_of_interest;
    Mat sfsrc;


};
Source_Buffer::Source_Buffer() :
sffiename("C:/ccc.jpg")

, sfregion_of_interest()
{

}

int Source_Buffer::run(){
    cout << "test" << endl;

    sfsrc = imread(sffiename, 0);
    sfregion_of_interest = Rect(90, 75, 250, 250);
    sfsrc = sfsrc(sfregion_of_interest);
return 0;
}
```

doenst work.
showing me " Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000." guess some null pointer stuff.
i tried to search some [Mat initializing in class] stuff but nothing i could find one.
what is wrong with my thinking here?

## source.cpp

```
#include "Source_Buffer.h"
int main()
        {
            try
            {
                cout << "(1) Start !" << endl;
                Source_Buffer sfbuffer;
                cout << "(2) running entrance" << endl;
                //Source_Game source_game;
                //source_game.runc();
                sfbuffer.run();
            }
            catch (std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cout << "\nEXCEPTION: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

## Source_Buffer.h

```
#pragma once


/*bridge*/
class Source_Buffer {

public:
    Source_Buffer();
    int run();

};
```

Comment: Hmm cannot reproduce, how/where did you use **Source_Buffer** class?

Comment: i added additional main code